# What can hand held metal circular saws not get through?

Tags: metal, cutting, circular-saw

This is not per se a DYI question, but someone here might know this: If you have a standard hand-held metal circular saw, what materials can it either not get through - or would clog it up?
Basically, I am looking for a strategy, that when someone tries to cut something with a metal saw they cant do it.
I was thinking maybe some kinds of fabric (felt, or those chainsaw protective clothings) or maybe if its a mix of materials so that once the metal blade gets trough metal it breaks at some other kind of material - does anyone have any clue what might work there?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "standard hand-held metal circular saw"? Do you mean a circular saw with a specific metal cutting blade? Do you mean an older saw with the entire body made of metal (as opposed to a newer one with a mostly plastic body)? Please feel free to [edit] your question to be _very_ much more explicit about exactly what kind of tool you're talking about and exactly what kind of cutting situation you're envisioning, as your question, as it stands, is rather unclear.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This sounds like a product design question, which is off-topic here. You should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about product design.

Comment: Blades which cut steel well do badly with concrete and vice versa.  Adding acrylic yarn to the mix will tend to foul both blade types.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that's thicker than the radius of the blade will be very hard to cut through.

Other than that with the right blade most materials can be cut.

something with loosely packed fibrous strands will tend to foul the axle.

Comment: I think you've hit on the only possible answer to this vague question